# MATLAB How to find the size of an array inside an array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, size

I have `x` and `x` is a `<1x106 cell>` now if I do `size(x,1)` I get 1 and `size(x,2)` I get 106. Now what I need to grab the column size for after this is `x(1,106)` which is a `<1x1 cell>` but when I open this it's actually a `{1x3503 cell}` however `size(x(1,106),2)` returns `1`. I figured it would be a simple case of choosing the the row and column inside x but woe is me!

Please don't laugh at me I know this mustn't be difficult and make me look a little like a muppet but until 4 days ago I never even used MATLAB so...

**Thanks for bearing with me!**
Cheers!

Comment: use `{}` for indexing cell elements, not `()` which creates another cell with the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between indexing the cells, or indexing the *contents of* the cells.

For the former, you use parentheses. So `x(1,106)` is just another cell array that contains the single cell stored in location (1,106) of `x`. It is *not* equal to the array that was stored into that cell of `x`... it's just a singleton cell array made up of that cell from `x`.

If instead you want to get the *contents of* that cell, then you use curly braces to do the indexing: `some_array = x{1,106}.`

Now, `some_array` will actually be the array that was stored in the (1,106) cell of `x`.

To highlight it another way, you could alternatively set `some_cell_array = x(1,106)` and then set `contents_array = some_cell_array{1,1}`, and then `contents_array` will actually be the array stored in that cell.